# Help required for making chess game for LAN

Tags: chess

I am a self-taught computer programming enthusiast. I have learn C, quite a bit of Java and am currently learning Python. At my college there is an internal LAN within the campus and recently I was struck with the idea of making a chess game than can be played by users within the campus through the LAN.

The game would be simply having a login system, where user can login with their usernames and passwords. On logging in, they would see a list of people who are currently online. They can challenge any of the players. The challenged player whould be notified of the challenge and can accept or decline it. Once accepted, the two players would play a one-on-one chess game (with time limitations). I would also like the players to be able to chat with each other. I guess its not too difficult to do so. :)

Although I have made small games before, but never a game that can be played online. Rather, I don't have much idea about the concepts of networking that would go into the making of this game. Could any of you give me an idea what all do I have to learn to make such an application?

I know a web-application using Jquery and AJAX would me quite easy to make, but I would like to make a desktop application.
Thanks in advance :) .

Comment: Ask a more specific question. This one is too vague.

Comment: This is a very difficult project for a college student. Are you sure?

Comment: @Kinderchodolate : Is it really that difficult ? I mean, the game would just be played by two people; I'm not planning to make a game in which the user plays against a computer. What's in it that makes you think its difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having a good chess engine, you need to learn about Threads and Sockets. so, you should create an UI for listening to a port (socket) and then create a list of online users. then one of them should be set as server (in order to run the chess algorithm) and receives other users inputs and update them with new situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, take a look at [Raknet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/). It simplifies a lot of the things that Dr TJ has mentioned and has several examples that you can take a look at. If you already know how to program a chess game, then making it multiplayer is trivial with libraries like Raknet. Again, take a look at the examples, it should give you a good start.